# FluentNHibernate One To Many Mapping

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am novice to NHibernate & FNH.  Below is the basic scenario I am trying to achieve
There are two entity mapper classes "Customer" & "Order"

## Customer

```
Table("CUSTOMERTEST");
            LazyLoad();
            Id(x => x.CustomerId).Column("CustomerId").GeneratedBy.Sequence("SYS");
            Map(x => x.CompanyName).Column("CompanyName");
            Map(x => x.ContactName).Column("ContactName");
            HasMany(x => x.Orders).KeyColumn("CustomerId").Cascade.All().Table("ORDERTEST").AsBag();
```

## Order

```
Table("ORDERTEST");
            LazyLoad();
            Id(x => x.OrderId).Column("OrderId").GeneratedBy.Sequence("SYS");
            References(x => x.OrderedBy).Column("CustomerId");
            References(x => x.ProductDetails).Column("ProductId");
            Map(x => x.OrderDate).Column("OrderDate");
            Map(x => x.ShipToName).Column("ShipToName");
```

I am trying to fetch the order details for a particular customer though property as below in the customer entity class.

```
public virtual IList<Order> Orders {
            get { return new List<Order>(orders).AsReadOnly(); }
            protected set { orders = value; }
        }
```

But I am able to fetch the customer details in the customer entity object  but he "Orders" for the particular customer is always empty.  I am not doing any update operations, I just need to fetch the data from DB only.  Amy I doing something wrong or how can we get this?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

In your Customer class:

```
public virtual IList<Order> Orders
        {
            get { return _orders; }
        }

private readonly IList<Order> _orders = new List<Order>();
```

also you can add public methods to add or remove items from Orders